# Ember loading state not triggered on transitionTo

Tags: ember.js, loading

If I use a transitionTo on a route with a slow model hook, the loading.hbs state never gets triggered (I have loading.hbs files at all of the levels --  cluster, cluster.schedule and cluster.schedule.preview_grid). I tried renaming the one at cluster.schedule `preview_grid-loading.hbs` with no luck.

On the transitionTo, there is no model or model id passed in, just the route:

`viewPreviewGrid: function() {
    this.transitionTo('cluster.schedule.preview_grid');
},`

I also have a loading action defined as follows:

```
loading(transition) {
    var controller = this.controller;
    if (!Ember.isNone(controller)) {
        this.controller.reset();
    }
    transition.promise.finally(function() {
        NProgress.done();
    });
}
```

During the transitionTo call the page just stays on the previous route until the promises in the model hook resolve, and then it transitions to the other route. If I refresh the page, the loading state gets triggered just fine. Is this a known behaviour for transitionTo?

This is my model hook:

```
model: function (/*params*/) {
var socialProfile = this.modelFor('cluster.schedule').get('firstObject');

if (!socialProfile.get('isInstagram')){
  throw new Error("Attempted to access preview with non-ig profile: " + socialProfile.get('id'));
}

var accessToken = socialProfile.get('token');

var self = this;

return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  igPosts: new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    self.getUsersRecentMedia(accessToken).then(function(response) {
      var igPosts = Ember.A([]);
      response.data.forEach(function(data) {
        igPosts.pushObject(self.igPostFromResponse(data, socialProfile));
      });

      resolve(igPosts);
    });
  }),
  posts: new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    self.store.query('gram', { type: 'preview', social_profile_id: socialProfile.get('id'), limit: self.get('postLimit') }).then(function(grams) {
      var filteredGrams = grams.filter(function(gram) {
        return (gram.get('scheduledInFuture')) && (gram.belongsTo('socialProfile').id() === socialProfile.get('id')) && (gram.get('active'));
      });

      resolve(filteredGrams);
    });
  }),
  igUser: new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    self.getSelf(accessToken).then(function(response) {
      resolve(self.igUserFromResponse(response.data, socialProfile));
    });
  })
});
```

},

Comment: Please add the code of your model-function.

Comment: @wuarmin updated question description to include the model hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return true` at the end of the `loading()` hook to tell Ember to go ahead and show the default loading route (`loading.hbs`).

```
loading(transition) {
  var controller = this.controller;
  if (!Ember.isNone(controller)) {
    this.controller.reset();
  }

  transition.promise.finally(function() {
    NProgress.done();
  });

  return true;
},
```